# Background image not showing up in div

Tags: html, css

My background image won't show up in the div I want to display in. However, it shows up if I put it in other elements. For example, I put it in the body element and it showed up just fine, but it won't display in the div I want it to. Can you check my code and see what I'm doing wrong. I double checked my file path and also the file type, and it's all fine. So, I'm not being able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "container container-flex">
            <div class = "title">
                <h1>PRODUCE</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class = "container container-flex">
        <main role = "main">
            <div class = "image">
            
            </div>

        </main> 
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header{
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width: 675px){
    .container-flex{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li{
    margin-left: 2em;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .25em 0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #575252;

}

h1{
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    margin: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    color: #FF344B;
}

@media (max-width: 675px){
    nav ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    nav li{
        margin: .5em 0;
    }
}

.image{
    background-image: url('logo.jpg');
    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are trying set background image in an empty element, which has 0 height.
Set specific width/height of the element.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header{
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width: 675px){
    .container-flex{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li{
    margin-left: 2em;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .25em 0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #575252;

}

h1{
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    margin: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    color: #FF344B;
}

@media (max-width: 675px){
    nav ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    nav li{
        margin: .5em 0;
    }
}

.image{
    background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj');
    height: 10em;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class = "container container-flex">
            <div class = "title">
                <h1>PRODUCE</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class = "container container-flex">
        <main role = "main">
            <div class = "image">

            </div>

        </main> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried it exactly how you showed but it still doesn't display the image :/

Comment: Open devtools and look for your element, it will tell you where it is on the page, it's dimensions and if background image applied to it. From there you can deduct where is the problem.

Comment: I just checked and everything seems fine. I edited the code again by setting the height to pixels instead of using em, and it worked. For some reason it is working with pixels but not with other units such as em and percentage.

Comment: must be because parent(s) element has 0 height/width

Answer (score 2):

Your div has no content. Either give some content or if that does not agree with your current design, give explicit height and width.

```css
.image{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image : url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg');
}

.image2{
background-image : url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>


<div class="image2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `width`, `height`, and `background-size` properties to the `.image`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header {
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 675px) {
  .container-flex {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .25em 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #575252;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  margin: 0.1em;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  color: #FF344B;
}

@media (max-width: 675px) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav li {
    margin: .5em 0;
  }
}

.container:nth-child(2){
  height: 250px;        /* set the height here */
}

main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Disk_pack1.svg/1200px-Disk_pack1.svg.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container container-flex">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>PRODUCE</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container container-flex">
    <main role="main">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Edit: You need to set the height on the second `.container` class. Because of no height, the relative units didn't work. Also, you need to set the height and width on parent (`main`) element of `.image`.

Comment: Okay this worked but the weird thing is if I set the width and height using pixels it works but if I set the width and height with percentage it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in answers by other users, your `div` element is empty and will sit on your page with effectively `height: 0px;` and `width: 0px;` properties.

To combat this, you should add a `width` property to your `.image` div in your stylesheets.

You can either then control the height of the image div with the `height` property, or alternatively you could use `padding-bottom` to give a more responsive twist to your styling, since `padding-bottom: x%` is a percentage of the element's width.

For example, adding:

```css
.image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

would create a square image that will stay responsively square as the page width, and therefore the width of the `div.iamge` element shrinks. The padding value can be played around with to get the right height for the element that you desire.

**UPDATE**

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container{ 
    background-color: red;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-wrapper {
  width: 75%;
}

.image {
  background-color: green;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
 }
 
 
 
 .container {
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
 }
 .center-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  
  <div class="container">
    container
    <main role="main">
      <div class="image-wrapper center-image">
        <div class="image">
          <span>image</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried all the solutions but the image displays when I set width and height with pixels. However, if I use percentage to set the width and height the image won't show up again.

Comment: @Nasheetat please see my updated answer to view a code snippet on how the padding-bottom technique should work. it might be advisable to wrap the image in an "image-wrapper" div to allow the height of the image to be factored into your design

Answer (score 0):

in your code if you setting an image in div tag it is should have a height and weight. This is another way to add images in your application with responsive.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header{
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width: 675px){
    .container-flex{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li{
    margin-left: 2em;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .25em 0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #575252;

}

h1{
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    margin: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    color: #FF344B;
}

@media (max-width: 675px){
    nav ul{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    nav li{
        margin: .5em 0;
    }
}

.image img{
width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Description Goes Here">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
        <div class = "container container-flex">
            <div class = "title">
                <h1>PRODUCE</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class = "container container-flex">
        <main role = "main">
            <div class = "image">
               <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="Smiley face">

            </div>

        </main> 
    </div>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```